# How to merge two objects and make sure when there's duplicated keys, take one of the objects' values first?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two objects created with [Lodash's groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) like this:

```
const prevGroupedData = {
  '01/04/2000': [{data: 1}, {data: 2}, {data: 3}],
  '02/04/2000': [{data: 1}, {data: 2}]
}

const GroupedData = {
  '02/04/2000': [{data: 3}, {data: 4}],
  '03/04/2000': [{data: 1}]
}
```

So when I merge these two objects, I wanna make sure that it is the prevGroupedData that is merged first, that means something like:

```
const result = {
  '01/04/2000': [{data: 1}, {data: 2}, {data: 3}],
  '02/04/2000': [{data: 1}, {data: 2}, {data: 3}, {data: 4}], 
  '03/04/2000': [{data: 1}]
}
```

But not:

```
const result = {
  '01/04/2000': [{data: 1}, {data: 2}, {data: 3}],
  '02/04/2000': [{data: 3}, {data: 4}, {data: 1}, {data: 2}], 
  '03/04/2000': [{data: 1}]
}
```

I have tried something like lodash's merge but it gives the second result:

```
let result = _.merge(prevGroupedData, GroupedData);
//gives second result
```

So how do I make sure that it is the prevGroupedData that has higher priority when there's duplicated keys?

Comment: @Teemu if I swap the arguments, something like 
`const result = {
  '03/04/2000': [{data: 1}],
  '02/04/2000': [{data: 3}, {data: 4}, {data: 1}, {data: 2}], 
  '01/04/2000': [{data: 1}, {data: 2}, {data: 3}]
}` 
would happen, which is not good

Comment: this should be possible with mergeWith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is possible with [`mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith). The docs have a similar looking example

```js
const prevGroupedData = {
  '01/04/2000': [{data: 1}, {data: 2}, {data: 3}],
  '02/04/2000': [{data: 1}, {data: 2}]
}

const GroupedData = {
  '02/04/2000': [{data: 3}, {data: 4}],
  '03/04/2000': [{data: 1}]
}
;

const customizer = (objValue, srcValue) => {
  if (_.isArray(objValue)) {
    return objValue.concat(srcValue)
  }
}
  
const res = _.mergeWith(prevGroupedData, GroupedData, customizer)
console.log(res)
console.log(prevGroupedData)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Note that the above has mutated the `prevGroupedData`. If you don't need that to happen you can assign an empty `{}` as the destination.

```js
const prevGroupedData = {
  '01/04/2000': [{data: 1}, {data: 2}, {data: 3}],
  '02/04/2000': [{data: 1}, {data: 2}]
}

const GroupedData = {
  '02/04/2000': [{data: 3}, {data: 4}],
  '03/04/2000': [{data: 1}]
}
;

const customizer = (objValue, srcValue) => {
  if (_.isArray(objValue)) {
    return objValue.concat(srcValue);
  }
}
 
// prevGroupedData not mutated, destination object is {} now
const res = _.mergeWith({},prevGroupedData, GroupedData, customizer)
console.log(res)
console.log(prevGroupedData)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

As `_.merge` does not handle combining arrays, you can use [`_.mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith) and pass a customizer to concatenate arrays.

```js
const prevGroupedData = {
  '01/04/2000': [{data: 1}, {data: 2}, {data: 3}],
  '02/04/2000': [{data: 1}, {data: 2}]
};
const GroupedData = {
  '02/04/2000': [{data: 3}, {data: 4}],
  '03/04/2000': [{data: 1}]
};
let result = _.mergeWith(prevGroupedData, GroupedData, (objVal, srcVal) => { 
  if (Array.isArray(objVal)) return objVal.concat(srcVal);
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```